# Problem with pgf library in TexLive

Tags: tikz-pgf, texlive, pgfkeys

I am using TexLive, and I am writing a paper with someone else.  He has sent me all of his files.  He uses tikz to draw commutative diagrams.

I am trying to compile his files, but I get an *undefined control sequence* error every time that `\pgfsetarrowoptions` is called in the `pgflibraryarrows.new.code` file.

It also doesn't seem to like the `\tikzset` command (same error), and I also get the following message:

> ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/align' and I am
>   going to  ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

It is working just fine for him, so there must be something wrong with the tikz / pgf library set up on my machine.

Here is the document header of the main .tex file:

```
% Math packages
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsgen,amsmath,amsxtra,amsfonts,mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}

% TikZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.new}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shapes,decorations.pathmorphing,arrows.new}
\tikzset{>=to new, arrow head=3pt}
```

It's not telling me that it can't find the tikz package.  Is it possible that I need to reinstall or update it?  If so, how should I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! It is most likely that you have different versions of tikz. Which TeX distribution do you use and which version do you have?

Comment: It looks that upgrading `texlive` on your computer might help with your problem. I use `tlmgr update --pause --self --all`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Without knowing the versions here we can't really hope to help.